# Multiple BIND DNS answers for a single IP address

Tags: dns, bind

please, could you help me on this?
we require to get correct configuration in BIND DNS in order to get multiple answers for unique IP address, like this:

```
$ORIGIN domain.com.
test        A       190.110.149.33
            A       190.110.149.33
            A       190.110.149.33
            A       190.110.149.97
```

So, when resolve APN test.domain.com. the idea is to receive answers 3 times with *.33 address and once for *.97. This is because we need to forward traffic 3 times in one device and once in another one.

The view accept the configuration but, when APN test is resolved, we got just one answer with *.33 and the another with *.97 ... just like round robin:

```
[root@SCLDORDNS1:Standby:Disconnected] namedb # dig test.domain.com.
...

;; ANSWER SECTION:
test.domain.com. 86400 IN A 190.110.149.33
test.domain.com. 86400 IN A 190.110.149.97
```

Would you have any suggestion to do it or to correct the last configuration?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to force a load balance using DNS... this is kind of a backwards way of doing it and doesn't mean *.33 will take 75% of the load while *.99 will take 25%. That said, the results are correct because BIND removes duplicate records. See here (just above 10.7.1) http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking_2ndEd/dns/ch10_07.htm

Comment: Thanks for your reply ..... so, it means that the next configuration could work:$ORIGIN domain.com.
test    60   IN   CNAME   foo1
test    60   IN   CNAME   foo2
test    60   IN   CNAME   foo3
test    60   IN   CNAME   foo4
foo1   60   IN   A   190.110.149.33
foo2   60   IN   A   190.110.149.33
foo3   60   IN   A   190.110.149.33
foo4   60   IN   A   190.110.149.97
do you think so?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment (some of it might be the formatting) but it still looks like you are using duplicate addresses, which would still be combined. Are you suggesting creating separate records cnames that would then be pointed to? That might work, but again is not recommended. You also couldn't use it as an apex record since cnames aren't allowed for the root.

Comment: Yes, the idea is to receive 3 answers from one IP address (*.33) and one from *.97 .... This is because we need to send traffic 3 times in one device (*.33) and onces to another one (*.97). Regards.

Comment: I have same problem, do you know how to solved it?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with BIND, you need specialized DNS server software that can respond to clients in a way that accomplishes the per-IP unbalanced load balancing that you want.  I could rattle off several vendors and service providers that can do this, but Google can tell you too... (http://google.com/?q=dns+gslb)

The best BIND can do is round-robin the multiple IPs in responses, and as you saw, ignores any duplicate records in the zone files.

Another way is to use a front-end redirector that can send three times the traffic to the .33 device...  plenty of reverse-proxy's out there you could use for that too.