# Allow bind answer multiple same ip addresses

Tags: networking, dns, bind

My issue is exactly like [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1118017/multiple-bind-dns-answers-for-a-single-ip-address)

But still no solution. But info I got is, bind9 doesn't allow answer multiple same ip addresses. So it remove the duplicate and left one.

If do it in bind9 is impossible, is there another way how to achieve my and his purpose like bind9 alternative?

If it's bind9 alternative, does that dns server allow fixed order in answering dns?

Comment: It might help if you would include what you are trying to achieve in your question.

Comment: thankyou for your respon, I already achieve it with programming way. I'm using python and ```dnslib``` as library. It worked as client and server

Comment: It might still help if you include the problem in your question, as well as adding an answer to help others in the future with the same problem

Comment: As someone mentioned in that thread answer, ```You can't do this with BIND, you need specialized DNS server software that can respond to clients in a way that accomplishes the per-IP unbalanced load balancing that you want```. So programmed DNS Server is actually a specialized DNS Server Software itself. Even I can freely whatever I can do.